# How to add same border to both input radio button and its label after radio has been checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

HTML:

```
<div class="form-check fs-3 mb-3">
  <input id="first_question" name="first_question" type="radio" value="n">
  <label for="first_question">no</label>
</div>
```

How to add same border to both input radio button and its label after radio has been checked ?

I have tried both:

```
.form-check:checked{
border:2px solid red;
border-radius: 4px;
color:red;
}
```

and :

```
.form-check::after{
border:2px solid red;
border-radius: 4px;
color:red;
}
```

But neither of them worked.Any friend can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `:has()` selector doesn't work in many browsers. Here is the [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/rakibul2010islam/pen/NWELmqd) to try it in different browsers.

```css
.form-check:has(> #first_question:checked){
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#first_question:checked:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;    
}

#first_question:checked + label{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check fs-3 mb-3">
  <input id="first_question" name="first_question" type="radio" value="n">
  <label for="first_question">Excellent</label>
</div>
```